# setClass make the representation be any class

Tags: r, r-s4

is there some way to allow one of my slots in a class to be **any** class?

i.e something like

> setClass("myClass", representation(A="any"))

I have tried "S4" but that is not working

Answer (score 1):

If you create a generic S4 function you should be able set an acceptable signature for method arguments to "ANY". I'm not sure if the representation could be set to "ANY" since the way I think about representations is more specific than that. Arguments that are not assigned signatures do get recorded with the "ANY" class. You could use the "vector" type as representation that can accept lists, or atomic objects:

```
setClass("myClass", representation(A="vector"))
[1] "myClass"
> new("myClass", A=list(a=c(2,3,4), b="a")  )
An object of class "myClass"
Slot "A":
$a
[1] 2 3 4

$b
[1] "a"
```

I'm not sure this is as general as you requested but you didn't say anything about needing attributes as well. I thought vector might lose attributes but it seems not:

```
> setClass("myClass", representation(A="vector"))
[1] "myClass"
> new("myClass", A=B  )
An object of class "myClass"
Slot "A":
$a
[1] 2 3 4

$b
[1] "a"

attr(,"myattr")
[1] "test"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice workaround in the source code of Paul Gilbert's TSdbi package.

```
setClassUnion("OptionalChar",   c("character",   "logical"))
setClass("myClass", representation(A="OptionalChar"))
```

This can be helpful when you expect `character` but want to allow for `NA`, too. I know this ain't 'ANY' but maybe you might want to restrict it, but not to a single mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "ANY".

```
> setClass("myClass", representation(A="ANY"))
> new("myClass", A=c(1,2,3))
An object of class "myClass"
Slot "A":
[1] 1 2 3
> new("myClass", A=unique)
An object of class "myClass"
Slot "A":
function (x, incomparables = FALSE, ...) 
UseMethod("unique")
<bytecode: 0x00000000071a8270>
<environment: namespace:base>
```